# Having trouble installing create-react-app...getting this error Cannot find module 'rxjs'

Tags: terminal, rxjs, create-react-app, npx

When using the command, `npx create-react-app tconnect` it fails with the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs'
```

I have the latest stable version of node.  I also tried reinstalling npm and yarn.

Below is the output from my terminal:

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
➜  Projects git:(master) ✗ npx create-react-app tconnect
npx: installed 91 in 3.968s

Creating a new React app in /Users/punchcode/Projects/tconnect.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.17.3
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 36 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.0.0
├─ react-dom@16.12.0
├─ react-scripts@3.3.0
└─ react@16.12.0
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.7.4
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators@7.7.4
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.7.4
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.7.4
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.7.4
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-decorators@7.8.3
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-flow@7.8.3
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.8.3
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-numeric-separator@7.8.3
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining@7.8.3
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@7.8.3
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@7.7.4
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.7.4
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.8.3
├─ @babel/preset-typescript@7.7.4
├─ @types/parse-json@4.0.0
├─ babel-plugin-macros@2.7.1
├─ babel-plugin-named-asset-import@0.3.5
├─ babel-preset-react-app@9.1.0
├─ core-js@3.6.4
├─ cra-template@1.0.0
├─ eslint-config-react-app@5.1.0
├─ fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@3.1.0
├─ lines-and-columns@1.1.6
├─ open@7.0.0
├─ promise@8.0.3
├─ raf@3.4.1
├─ react-app-polyfill@1.0.5
├─ react-dev-utils@10.0.0
├─ react-dom@16.12.0
├─ react-error-overlay@6.0.4
├─ react-scripts@3.3.0
├─ react@16.12.0
├─ scheduler@0.18.0
├─ whatwg-fetch@3.0.0
└─ yaml@1.7.2
✨  Done in 9.23s.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'rxjs'
Require stack:
- /Users/punchcode/Projects/tconnect/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js
- /Users/punchcode/Projects/tconnect/node_modules/inquirer/lib/inquirer.js
- /Users/punchcode/Projects/tconnect/node_modules/react-dev-utils/browsersHelper.js
- /Users/punchcode/Projects/tconnect/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/init.js
- /Users/punchcode/Projects/tconnect/[eval]
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/punchcode/Projects/tconnect/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js:3:34)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/punchcode/Projects/tconnect/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js',
    '/Users/punchcode/Projects/tconnect/node_modules/inquirer/lib/inquirer.js',
    '/Users/punchcode/Projects/tconnect/node_modules/react-dev-utils/browsersHelper.js',
    '/Users/punchcode/Projects/tconnect/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/init.js',
    '/Users/punchcode/Projects/tconnect/[eval]'
  ]
}

Aborting installation.
  node  has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting tconnect/ from /Users/punchcode/Projects
Done.
```

Comment: You really should include the commands you entered at the teerminal so users of the site can see why you might have got the above output.

Comment: Thanks...here is the command I used:  npx create-react-app tconnect

Comment: You might try simply `npm install create-react-app` and the running the `create-react-app` command.

Another option is to try and install `create-react-app` via Yarn.

Comment: @captainrad ..thats, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

It could be a number of things. I'd suggest a sanity check, in which case we'll assume that something is broken in your particular case with `npx`-

So try the alternatives:

1. `npm install create-react-app` and then `create-react-app`
2. **OR** install `create-react-app` via Yarn

If this doesn't work try Facebook's suggestion (in the event you may have installed create-react-app globally):

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm
>   install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package
>   using npm uninstall -g create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses
>   the latest version.

*source: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/README.md*